# SOAP server reads web method parameters as null

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a client that connects to a SOAP server endpoint:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/todo", new ToDoWebService());
```

The **server** offers the next simple method:

```
@WebService
public class ToDoWebService {

    @WebMethod()
    public String addToDo(String task, String context, String project, int priority) {
        return "ToDo: \n "
                + "\t Task    :  "+task+"\n"
                + "\t Context :  "+context+"\n"
                + "\t Project :  "+project+"\n"
                + "\t Priority:  "+priority;
    }
}
```

This is the **client**:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToDoWebServiceService tdwss = new ToDoWebServiceService();
        ToDoWebService tdws = tdwss.getToDoWebServicePort();

        System.out.println(tdws.addToDo("Task 1","My Context","My Project",9));
    }
}
```

The thing is that the connection between client and server is succesful, but not entirely: the pass of the arguments from the client to the service is not made as expected, been this the result on the client once executed:

[image]

The server doesn't receive correctly the arguments that the client has passed with the method "addToDo()" call. It returns the string format expected but with *nulls* instead the arguments passed by the client. And that's what I can't figure out...

Of course, I'm pretty confident the **WSDL file** is well written:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. -->
    <definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://todows.bigws/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://todows.bigws/" name="ToDoWebServiceService">
        <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://todows.bigws/" schemaLocation="toDo.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        </types>
        <message name="addToDo">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:addToDo"/>
        </message>
        <message name="addToDoResponse">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:addToDoResponse"/>
        </message>
        <portType name="ToDoWebService">
            <operation name="addToDo">
                <input wsam:Action="http://todows.bigws/ToDoWebService/addToDo" message="tns:addToDo"/>
                <output wsam:Action="http://todows.bigws/ToDoWebService/addToDoResponse" message="tns:addToDoResponse"/>
            </operation>
        </portType>
        <binding name="ToDoWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:ToDoWebService">
            <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
            <operation name="addToDo">
                <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
        <service name="ToDoWebServiceService">
            <port name="ToDoWebServicePort" binding="tns:ToDoWebServicePortBinding">
                <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/todo"/>
            </port>
        </service>
    </definitions>
```

As well as the ***schema "toDo.xsd"***:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. -->
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://todows.bigws/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://todows.bigws/">

    <xs:element name="addToDo" type="tns:addToDo"/>

    <xs:element name="addToDoResponse" type="tns:addToDoResponse"/>

    <xs:complexType name="addToDo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="task" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="context" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="project" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="addToDoResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I've tried different actions in the server method, as writing the string with the parameter in a file, but the result is the same, an error cause the parameters are *null*. That's what I think proves that the failure is located in the way the server receive the parameters passed to the *"addToDo()"* method.

I've review the WSDL & schema files over and over....but I've not been able to find what make this code run wrongly. I've also tested this code with the SoapUI software and the outcome is the same.
¿Any ideas?

P.D.: Sorry about all the posted code.

In case you need the whole project: [my SOAP project at GitHub](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/tree/developer/553939_Lab1_SOAP)

Comment: Could you provide some link to your code? I would like to reproduce the issue.

Comment: When you test with [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), the behaviour is identical? i.e. you send ("Task 1","My Context","My Project",9) and the server unmarshall the message to  (null, null, null, 0)

Comment: Done, added a link with all the code.

Yes, exactly the same behaviour with SoapUI.

@FranciscoJ.Lopez-Pellicer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reviewed your WSDL and XSD in your project [todows-cli-ws](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/WebEng2014/tree/developer/553939_Lab1_SOAP/todows-cli-ws) and the problem is **the WSDL and XSD files in your client project are outdated**!

For example, this is the current content of the XSD file of your server.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://todows.bigws/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
    version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://todows.bigws/">
 <xs:element name="addToDo" type="tns:addToDo"/>
 <xs:element name="addToDoResponse" type="tns:addToDoResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="listToDo" type="tns:listToDo"/>
 <xs:element name="listToDoResponse" type="tns:listToDoResponse"/>
 <xs:element name="removeToDo" type="tns:removeToDo"/>
 <xs:element name="removeToDoResponse" type="tns:removeToDoResponse"/>
 <xs:complexType name="addToDo">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="arg3" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="addToDoResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="removeToDo">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="removeToDoResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="listToDo">
  <xs:sequence/>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="listToDoResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that the current name of the params are *arg0*, *arg1*, *arg2* and *arg3*. The server expects as param names *task*, *context*, *project* and *priority*, and therefore the method is invoked with the default values (*null* for a *String* and *0* for an *int*).

Comment: Many thanks! That was the problem, I've updated the params name in the client **_.XSD_** file to _arg0, arg1..._ and it works perfectly.